# How Can I get NUnit's ExpectedException attribute to detect an exception's base class?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.5, tibco-ems

Using `NUnit 2.5.10`, I am testing some code that references a library containing a base exception type. `TIBCO.EMS.NamingException`, from which other exception types derive, specifically `TIBCO.EMS.InvalidNameException` and `TIBCO.EMS.NameNotFoundException`.

I would like to use NUnit's ExpectedException attribute to recognize when any subclassed exception deriving from `TIBCO.EMS.NamingException` has been thrown.

I can easily detect when the specific exception has been thrown:

```cs
[ExpectedException("TIBCO.EMS.NameNotFoundException")]
       or 
[ExpectedException(Typeof(TIBCO.EMS.InvalidNameException))]
```

But I would like to somehow make NUnit "expect" whether any subclass of `TIBCO.EMS.NamingException` has been thrown.

Trying it directly does not work:

```cs
[ExpectedException("TIBCO.EMS.NamingException")]
    or
[ExpectedException(typeof(TIBCO.EMS.NamingException))]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [NUnit documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5):

```cs
// Allow both ApplicationException and any derived type
Assert.Throws( Is.InstanceOf( typeof(ApplicationException), code );
Assert.Throws( Is.InstanceOf<ApplicationException>(), code );
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  I was so enamored of the ExpectedException attribute, which I have used so helpfully so many times before, that I missed going back to a different part of the documentation.  I was trying to make a glove do the duty of a boot!  Thank you, @silev for teaching me a useful new trick!

Comment: Great, you are welcome!  Also I like generic version Assert.Throws<TException>() and very useful Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => { ... })